# jsondecodeerror in db2 jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, db2, anaconda

I am a complete novice in this area and trying to understand

I have a linux machine with anaconda, python, ibm_db, jupyter notebooks installed

I am following a pdf to activate a db2 connection from notebook

started jupyter : ok

open new notebook and : %run db2.ipynb

this notebook I downloaded from
https://github.com/DB2-Samples/db2jupyter

Only one file is needed: db2.ipynb
when running this notebook I get an error

> JSONDecodeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>   /Software/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbformat/reader.py in
>   parse_json(s, **kwargs) 13 try: —> 14 nb_dict = json.loads(s,
>   **kwargs) 15 except ValueError:
>
> /Software/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/json/init.py in loads(s, encoding,
>   cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant,
>   object_pairs_hook, **kw) 347 parse_constant is None and
>   object_pairs_hook is None and not kw): –> 348 return
>   _default_decoder.decode(s) 349 if cls is None:
>
> /Software/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s,
>   _w) 336 “”" –> 337 obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()) 338 end = _w(s, end).end()
>
> /Software/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self,
>   s, idx) 354 except StopIteration as err: –> 355 raise
>   JSONDecodeError(“Expecting value”, s, err.value) from None 356 return
>   obj, end
>
> **JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 1 (char 6)**
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> NotJSONError Traceback (most recent call last)

can this error be related to setup or is something specific needed, that was noted in the install procedure ?

thanks for all update
best regards, Guy Przytula

Comment: Which linux distro is this, and which version? I run ubuntu 18.04 and in a virtualenv the `db2.ipynb` appears to work as expected.

Comment: `db2.ipynb` also works for me on RHEL 7.7 with anaconda 2020.02, after modifying `db2.ipynb` with the database connection details. Then the %sql works as expected (with local sample database).  Maybe edit your question to include a link to the PDF that you are following.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all update
in the mean time, found the problem and has been corrected
the problem was the download : when being on github file list I richt clicked and save as..
in this case the file is corrupted
downloaded the file with : download zipfile - that downloaded the folder with all files as a zipfile. then unpacked the zipfile and use the db2 notebook
I also found that you could view raw data from notebook and save as..
thks for all update
best regards, Guy